# Get and passing value from input HTML into Controler

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I'm having an input html like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder=" " value="@Model.studentName.firstName">
```

How can I get and passing `value="@Model.studentName.firstName"` into Controller when user typing?

My code controller simple like this

```
if (p.Text != null && p.Text.Contains("{1}"))
                            {
                                p.ReplaceText("{1}", valueHTML);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not stating which version of.net you're using, I'm going to assume you're using .NET Core, in that case you can Bind the property to the controller, which means that when you hit the submit button the controller will store or update the state of the binded property and pass it to all the actions contained within that controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```